# Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in stmt

Tags: php, mysql, sql, bind, param

Trying to take input from the user which will then put them in my database. Getting "Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference" error o the mysqli_stmt_bind_param line.

```
        if(empty($_POST['Name'])){

            $missdata[] = 'Name';

         } else {
        $p_name = trim($POST['Name']);
        }

        if(empty($_POST['Platform'])){

            $missdata[] = 'Platform';

         } else {
        $p_platform = trim($POST['Platform']);
        }

        if(empty($_POST['Price'])){

            $missdata[] = 'Price';

         } else {
        $p_price = trim($POST['Price']);
        }

        if(empty($_POST['Stock'])){

            $missdata[] = 'Stock';

         } else {
        $p_stock = trim($POST['Stock']);
        }

        if(empty($missdata)){
            require_once('./connect.php');

            $query = "INSERT INTO Products (id, Name, Platform, Price, Stock) VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)";

            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssdd', $p_name, p_platform, $p_price, $p_stock);

            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            $affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
```

Comment: Exactly what it says. Only variables can be passed through. Variables have $ signs in front of them. 'ssdd' does not, hence the error message.

Comment: The ssdd is to represent the data types of the inputs, have I done it wrong?

Comment: I'd (temporarily) remove it or sign it as $ssdd, and sign p_platform as $p_platform as well. And see if that works. I'm no guru on php either, this error message just seems to explain itself rather well.

Comment: 'ssdd' is fine - It's because you're missing $ in front of p_platform.